# Help with SVN Setup

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I am setting up VisualSVN. It comes with a "Repositories" repo. My question is pretty simple I hope, do I create a single repository under the root and then add a new folder for each project I want to manage? or do I create a new repository under the root "Repositores" for each new project?

Comment: Many of the projects will be mostly independent; however, I would like to be able to create add projects to the repository from the road w/out access to the server console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have all of my projects in a single repository.  Each project gets a folder with a trunk, tags, and branches subfolder.  One drawback to this is that any commit increments the revision of the repository, but I don't show the revision number anywhere in my code.

Comment: IMHO, the revision ID is more a "serial number" than a "build number".  Therefore, as long as it's unique, it's fulfilling its purpose and shouldn't dissuade one from managing multiple projects in one repository.

Comment: I've read you cannot create a repository w/out console access...can you create these folders with trunk, tags, and branches from TrotoiseSVN for example?

Comment: I don't think the increasing number is a drawback, revision numbers are cheap

Comment: a drawback may come if you want to restrict access to certains projects. can I set different access politics on folder level?

Comment: nevermind (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz)

Answer (score 1):

If your projects are related, then I would create a single repository under the root and then add a new folder for each project I want to manage. A single repository could contain a project group which contains different projects.

If your projects are unrelated, then create a new repository for each project. Then each project will belong to different project group.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

- Chapter 5 of the SVN Book delves into this question:
  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout
- You cannot perform svn copy/svn move operations between repositories, but you can between directories.
- It's more of an art than a science, and it comes down to how much source code the projects will be sharing.